# Json parsing C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, parsing, exception

I had a Json like this

```
{ "nodes" : [{"id" : "36018","title" : "Fotarı","date" : "20.09.2012 00:45", "short_description" : "Dünrina, rr!","bigimage_width" : "468","bigimage" : "https://qew","croppedimage" : "https://qwe.jpg"},{"id" : "36009","title" : "ey","date" : "20.09.2012 00:03", "short_description" : "İntız!","bigimage_width" : "220","bigimage" : "https://312.jpg","croppedimage" : "https://41172.jpg"},{"id" : "35915","title" : "ai!","date" : "20.09.2012 00:02", "short_description" : "Ssdi...","bigimage_width" : "220","bigimage" : "https://qwe.qwe" : "https://asd.asd"},...
```

so i did this

```
JObject j = JObject.Parse(x); // x is downloaded JSon code
JArray sonuc = (JArray)j["nodes"];
```

but now i have

```
[{"id":"1","name":"news"},{"id":"2","name":"hardware"},{"id":"3","name":"software"},{"id":"4","name":"\internet"},{"id":"6","name":"tv!"},{"id":"7","name":"texts"},{"id":"8","name":"update"},...
```

so what should i do with my code to make it work?

```
JObject j = JObject.Parse(x); // gives JsonReaderException exception here
JArray sonuc = (JArray)j[""];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an array in JSON (notice the opening `[` and closing `]` brackets)  you can directly parse it with the [JArray.Parse](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm) static method:

```
JArray sonuc = JArray.Parse(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to parse your json, for example, you can use `dynamic`

```
dynamic obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var node in obj1.nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", node.id, node.title);
}
```

or linq

```
var obj2 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var nodes= obj2["nodes"].Children()
            .Select(node => new
            {
                Id= (string)node["id"],
                Title = (string)node["title"]
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: i didn't understand what deserializeObject does. i using this after convert json to jsonArray temp.name = (string)sonuc[i]["name"];
temp.id = Int32.Parse((string)sonuc[i]["id"]);//in a for loop